# Cannot set 16:9 resolution on ubuntu 12.04 run in VirtualBox

Tags: virtualbox, ubuntu-12.04, widescreen

I recently installed virtualbox. I tried to run ubuntu 10.04 and it worked fine in fullhd resolution. Then I installed Ubuntu 12.04 and now when I to setup up any fullhd resolution UI becomes very slow, almost unusable. Other high resolutions work fine (for example 1600x1200. I am not sure what the source of the problem might be. (I have guest additions). Thank you for help!

Comment: If that's fresh installation, you'll probably need to install [Guest Additions](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch04.html). God help you otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

I have been faced with the same problem, when I came upon [this ticket](https://www.virtualbox.org/ticket/7621) at virtualbox.org, by user "SB1234", last post:

> I tried the work around to set the modes the width to 1 pixel less
>   than the actual width. And it worked for me in fullscreen. However
>   after exiting from full screen the resolution remained at that value.
>   (it did not auto adjust)
>
> Anyway after rummaging through more links online i found out that
>   there are certain workarounds in the compiz settings manager. i was
>   able to find one particular option that solves this problem (Yippie!!)
>
> first you need to install compizconfig-settings-manager using sudo
>   apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager.
>
> Then in Preferences->Compizconfig-settings-manager look for Utility.
>   And then 'check' the workaround item. Finally in the settings for the
>   workaround item, look for 'Force fullscreen redraws (buffer swap) on
>   repaint' and check this option. Thats it!
>
> It worked for me. I had been looking for a fix for several weeks.:D
>
> Win7x64 bit host. Virtualbox 4.1.8 with Ubuntu 11.04. (amd64) guest. I
>   have a intel hd 3000 on board graphics card.

This also worked for me, Ubuntu 12.04.1 LTS, Intel hd 3000, VirtualBox 4.2.2.